# Getting error regarding calling a custom function from binding formatCurrency()

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**Error message is ReferenceError: formatCurrency is not defined**

here is my jsfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3bu6nybk/`

please some one see my jsfiddle link and tell me why i am getting this error message Error message is **ReferenceError: formatCurrency is not defined**

formatCurrency is defined in same place

```
 function formatCurrency(value) {
           alert(value.toFixed(2));
          return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
      }
```

and i am calling like this way `<span data-bind='text:formatCurrency(subtotal())'>`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added formatCurrency to Cart, but it's being accessed inside a CartLine loop, so when you reference it, knockout tries to look for the function in the CartLine object. If you use $root.formatCurrency it should work as it will look in the root scope, which in this case is a Cart object

```
 <td ><span data-bind='text:$root.formatCurrency(subtotal())'></span></td>
```

I've updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/omerio/3bu6nybk/2/

Comment: yes worked. if i declare formatCurrency function inside CartLine function. i tried and call without $root keyword then got the same error. any idea

Comment: `var CartLine = function () 
{
          var self = this;
          self.formatCurrency = function (value) 
          {
             return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
          }
              
});`

and try to access like this way `<span data-bind='text:formatCurrency(subtotal())'>` but got error. any idea

Comment: Your suggested change seems to work fine, see here http://jsfiddle.net/omerio/3bu6nybk/4/

Comment: Did u change anything or just copy my code and it works?

Answer (score 1):

It seams that KO looks for the function in its context, and `new CartLine().formatCurrency === undefined`.

A fix would be:

```
var CartLine = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.formatCurrency = formatCurrency;
  // ...
  // ...
```

But IDK if you can actually refer to global functions in KO binds.

Comment: i follow your code but still not fixed. so please have a look my code. here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3bu6nybk/1/